# Aggregate function over a subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, aggregate-functions

I think I've hit a limitation of SQL queries here. My table schema looks like the following:

```sql
create table sessions (sessionId integer, browser text, ...);
-- primary key: sessionId

create table pageviews (sessionId integer, pageViewIndex integer, path text, ...);
-- primary key: sessionId, pageViewIndex

create table properties (sessionId integer, pageViewIndex integer, name text, value text);
-- primary key: sessionId, pageViewIndex, name
```

Same columns are related. This is a very simple database draft without foreign keys. It's created with SQLite and designed only to work in SQLite.

A session contains one or more associated pageViews. A pageView may contain zero or more properties, each with a different name, and their set value.

I want to find all distinct browsers of all sessions and assign them the average value of a certain assigned property on their pageViews, and sort by that value. I know that this can only work if the property's values are numeric. The user of the query has to care about that.

Sample data:

**sessions:**

| sessionId | browser |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | firefox |
| 2 | firefox |
| 3 | brave |
| 4 | firefox |

**pageviews:**

| sessionId | pageViewIndex | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xyz |
| 1 | 2 | xyz |
| 2 | 1 | xyz |
| 3 | 1 | xyz |
| 4 | 1 | xyz |

(sessionId 1 has two pageviews, the others just one; the paths are irrelevant here)

**properties:**

| sessionId | pageViewIndex | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | a | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | a | 80 |

(sessionId 1, pageViewIndex 1 and sessionId 4 don't have the property set, so they're not regarded by this statistical query.)

The expected query result is this:

| browser | a_avg |
| --- | --- |
| brave | 80 |
| firefox | 15 |

That is because there were 2 sessions with firefox (ID 1 and 2) that had pageViews with the property "a" values 10 and 20, there was 1 session with brave (ID 3) that had pageViews with the property "a" value 80.

My query needs to allow filtering by any columns as well, so it should be as minimal as possible without fancy side effects of joins and such. In fact, the main query joins are fixed and cannot be changed. For example, the considered data might be filtered on other columns in the sessions table or the pageviews table, or even associated properties (via a subquery). That filtering part already works perfectly on its own and it should not be destroyed by this query.

My current effort is this:

```sql
select s.browser,
  (select avg(value)
    from properties pr
    where pr.sessionId = p.sessionId and pr.pageViewIndex = p.pageViewIndex and pr.name = 'a') a_avg,
from sessions s
  join pageviews p on (p.sessionId = s.sessionId)
group by s.browser
order by a_avg desc
```

But that returns wrong values. Instead of the `avg` I tried `group_concat` to inspect the values being averaged here. But instead of all relevant values, only a single value is shown here. So something must be severely broken in this query. I'd have tried this instead, but subqueries are apparently not allowed in aggregate functions:

```sql
select s.browser,
  avg(select value
    from properties pr
    where pr.sessionId = p.sessionId and pr.pageViewIndex = p.pageViewIndex and pr.name = 'a') a_avg,
from sessions s
  join pageviews p on (p.sessionId = s.sessionId)
group by s.browser
order by a_avg desc
```

Is there any hope that this can be solved within SQL, without fetching all the raw records and doing the statistics all in application memory?

Comment: I don't get these restrictions, but [here is dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W6JgbuUI) that might be useful.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a correlated subquery use simple joins of all 3 tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT s.browser,
       AVG(pr.value) a_avg
FROM sessions s
JOIN pageviews pv ON pv.sessionId = s.sessionId
JOIN properties pr ON pr.sessionId = pv.sessionId AND pr.pageViewIndex = pv.pageViewIndex
-- WHERE <here you can set your filters>
GROUP BY s.browser
ORDER BY a_avg DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/i969eD42).